# What content-type do I use for http response headers that contain a file attachment of unknown file type?

Tags: c#, http, content-type, attachment

Right now I am not specifying it and the system is defaulting to text/html which is causing some not so good results like downloading a movie on my iPhone is giving me a massive block of text so large that it crashes the browser for example. What content-type should I use? It could literally be any file type as the attachment. Content-disposition is attachment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `application/octet-stream`.